# Merge a copy of one pandas DataFrame into every row of another DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a scenario where I want to expand a dataframe by merging in another, smaller table into every row of the dataframe.

In other words, if the larger table is 10 rows, and the small table is 2 rows, then the result would be a table of length 20 where every row in the original table is duplicated and the new columns from the smaller table are merged.

To accomplish this, I have written a small function that adds a common column onto each table, merges on that column, then drops the column.

```
def merge_expand(big, small):
    placeholder = "__placeholderstring__"
    big.insert(0, placeholder, 1)
    small.insert(0, placeholder, 1)
    merged = big.merge(small, how='left', on=placeholder)
    merged.drop(columns=placeholder, inplace=True)
    return merged

# example
big = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
small = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['aa','bb'], 'val':['a','b']})
merge_expand(big, small)

# output:
   a  b  id val
0  1  4  aa   a
1  1  4  bb   b
2  2  5  aa   a
3  2  5  bb   b
4  3  6  aa   a
5  3  6  bb   b
```

This does the job, but seems to me that it is hacky and may not be the most efficient solution, as it needs to perform multiple DataFrame operations. What would be the most efficient way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are looking for a full join / cartesian join. It can be accomplished with `pd.merge` if we assign the same `key` to all observations.

```py
big.assign(key=1).merge(small.assign(key=1), how='outer', on='key')
```

Output

```py
   a  b  key  id val
0  1  4    1  aa   a
1  1  4    1  bb   b
2  2  5    1  aa   a
3  2  5    1  bb   b
4  3  6    1  aa   a
5  3  6    1  bb   b
```

If you already have a columns called 'key', you can essentially call it anything:

```py
big['thiswontmatchanything'] = 1
small['thiswontmatchanything'] = 1

big.merge(small, how='outer', on='thiswontmatchanything').drop('thiswontmatchanything', axis=1)
```

Output

```
    a   b   id  val
0   1   4   aa  a
1   1   4   bb  b
2   2   5   aa  a
3   2   5   bb  b
4   3   6   aa  a
5   3   6   bb  b
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution. One problem I see is that if "key" is already a column name, it will overwrite all that data. I wonder if there is a fast way to make sure a column "key" doesn't exist

Comment: @teepee, you can call it anything really, let me update with another example

Comment: sorry I meant to say that it's not always going to be robust, as the string for joining could potentially be in the columns already. You can minimize the risk with obscure column naming but it still feels like a hack. But your solution is great so thanks for providing it.

Comment: hi, this should work for me but i get a memory error while doing it.. {MemoryError: Unable to allocate 14.6 GiB for an array with shape (1960000000,) and data type int64}. any other way to do so? the big df is 1000000x2 and small about 1960x4

Comment: Hi @agr, there are a few ways to approach it in case of memoryError: (1) change from int64 to int32/int16/int8 if you don't actually need an int64 data type range. (2) split the file , merge and write to file / stream as opposed to holding in memory. The ideal here is try to understand what needs to be done after the full cartesian join and try to perform that either in steps, or apply it before the join (whenever possible)

Comment: i made a million samples of 132 bit data and i have only 2,000 actual error vectors(and other data) to check on the data. what i did for now is concating the error vectors untill its size is mil rows, afterwareds i merged it to the samples df.. i just thoughts that there is a better formulated way to do so.. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I believe there is a much shorter way. Given data frames df1 and df2, you could do

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

or

```
df = df2.merge(df1, how='cross')
```

You could potentially implement a simple if-then-else to figure out which data frame is smaller or larger. But that's besides the merging operation.

Comment: This is the best solution now. It has only been in Pandas since 1.2.0 (Dec. 2020).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly less hacky is the following:

Each dataframe replicates rows by the length of the other orgiinal dataframe
The first one is ordered by the 'a' column, but you could adjust that
Then the two dataframes are concatenated along hte column axis (1) to achieve the desired result.

```
def merge_expand(*args):
    tmp_big = pd.concat([args[0]] * len(small), ignore_index=True).sort_values(by=['a']).reset_index(drop=True)
    tmp_small = pd.concat([args[1]] * len(big), ignore_index=True)
    return pd.concat([tmp_big, tmp_small], 1)
```

Input:

```
merge_expand(big, small)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  id val
0  1  4  aa   a
1  1  4  bb   b
2  2  5  aa   a
3  2  5  bb   b
4  3  6  aa   a
5  3  6  bb   b
```

EDIT: We can even make it a bit more generic if you want to pass a few arguments:

```
def merge_expand(*args):
    if len(args) == 2:
        if len(args[0]) > len(args[1]):
            df_1 = pd.concat([args[0]] * len(args[1]), ignore_index=True).sort_values(by=[args[0].columns[0]]).reset_index(drop=True)
            df_2 = pd.concat([args[1]] * len(args[0]), ignore_index=True)
            return pd.concat([df_1, df_2], 1)
```